# Debug Remote Ajax In Ripple Emulator

Tags: cordova, ripple

I've got a cordova app with a simple (jquery) ajax post:

```
var jqxhr = $.post({
  url: 'http://example.com/api/v1/authenticate',
  data: { 
    a: $('#a').val(),
    b: $('#b').val(),
  },
}).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  alert( data );
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
  alert( textStatus );
});
```

When I fire up a ripple emulate session, trigger the code above, and watch what's going in the chrome console, I see the a POST fire, but the URL is:

```
http://localhost:4400/[object%20Object]
```

This, of course, yields a 404.

In the ripple session, I have Cross Domain Proxy turned off; so, theoretically it shouldn't be getting in the way, but I can't figure out why its not using the specified URL.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

argh, operator error.  the jquery syntax was wrong.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com/api/v1/authenticate',
  data: { 
    a: $('#a').val(),
    b: $('#b').val(),
  },
}).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  alert( data );
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
  alert( textStatus );
});
```

With that fixed, the correct URL is being POSTed to.